# serving files through Puppet: "Could not evaluate"

Tags: puppet

**TLDR version:** Given a normal use of fileserver.conf, how do I build a puppet URL that will actually work?

.

I'm trying to get started with Puppet and a few virtual instances. For a first task, I'm trying to distribute an authorized_keys file using the [file type](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file). Yes, it can be done with the [ssh authorized key type](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#sshauthorizedkey), but this is about *file distribution* for now, right?

The [file serving wiki](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/file_serving.html) implies the paths I should be constructing. First, here's what puppetmasterd knows:

```
$ grep -B 1 path /etc/puppet/fileserver.conf 
[files]
  path /etc/puppet
```

Second, I created a file, `/etc/puppet/modules/ssh/manifests/init.pp`, that contains the following:

```
$ cat /etc/puppet/modules/ssh/manifests/init.pp
class ssh {
  file { "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys":
    source => "puppet:///modules/ssh/authorized_keys",
    mode => 400,
    owner => ubuntu,
    group => ubuntu
  }

  file { "/home/ubuntu/.ssh":
    ensure => directory,
    mode => 700,
    owner => ubuntu,
    group => ubuntu
  }

  notify {"all done.":}

}

# declare class
class {'ssh':}
```

When I run the file directly, it fails in the following way:

```
$ puppet apply --verbose /etc/puppet/modules/ssh/manifests/init.pp
info: Applying configuration version '1357516270'
notice: all done.
notice: /Stage[main]/Ssh/Notify[all done.]/message: defined 'message' as 'all done.'
err: /Stage[main]/Ssh/File[/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///modules/ssh/authorized_keys at /etc/puppet/modules/ssh/manifests/init.pp:7
notice: Finished catalog run in 0.04 seconds
```

I've tried several versions of the puppet source link. For instance:

```
puppet:///modules/ssh/authorized_keys
puppet:///authorized_keys
```

Here's where the authorized_keys file *actually* resides:

```
$ ls -l /etc/puppet/modules/ssh/files/authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 root root 796 Jan  6 23:30 authorized_keys
```

This pattern of "init.pp" and "files/*" appears to match the [Advanced Puppet Pattern wiki entry](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Advanced_Puppet_Pattern#Resulting-Tree-of-etcpuppet-Files).

Here's my puppet version, for completeness.

```
$ puppet --version
2.7.18
```

To show I'm not doing the "fix my simple question" or "do my homework" thing, I've been working to find answers to this basic question. I have included links above to reference sources, and I've looked at [other](https://serverfault.com/a/410092) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762834/custom-mount-point-not-working-on-puppet) too. I've seen failures that are cert issues ([1](https://serverfault.com/questions/332954/puppet-cert-mismatch-in-ec2), [2](https://serverfault.com/questions/388957/puppet-not-signing-cert-or-getting-new-requests)), but this is local. Annoyingly, [this looks very close but takes a hard turn into Vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216375/how-to-source-a-file-in-puppet-manifest-from-module), though there's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7590044/659298) that talks about a `[modules]` section instead of a `[files]` section, which doesn't exist in the wiki. [Here's a recent "official mailing list" thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/puppet-users/ybuBQJf2VSY), but I couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Where did you put the file `authorized_keys`?

Comment: oops, I'll add that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure something like this is set to the path of your modules in puppet.conf on your master

```
  modulepath = /etc/puppet/modules
```

If you then do something like

```
 source => "puppet:///modules/ssh/authorized_keys",
```

If will look for the file in

```
 /etc/puppet/modules/ssh/files/authorized_keys
```

EDIT:

you are mixing up files with modules btw.. they are two completely different things. Generally everyone uses modules these days and never touches [files] since it is too messy.

Comment: yep, this did it. (though I've backed the modulepath change out and it still seems to work). It's nice to know what people use, not just what's out there- thanks!

Comment: This also fixed a Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) problem that I was having.  The fact that "files" doesn't show up in the URL was throwing me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Any logs on your master?

That location is correct, but I suspect the `600` mode on the file is preventing the file server from being able to read it, since the puppet master process usually runs as a non-root user (`puppet` by default).

Check the logs, but a mode change on the file will probably do the trick.

Comment: there's nothing in the server logs, just on the "client" side :-( I changed perms to 666 on the file, it didn't work. Directories are 755.

Comment: oh, the only serverlog is the masterhttp.log.